# Doctrine hydrate not mapped field

Tags: symfony, doctrine

I am making a query with Doctrine which calculates a custom field using a `CASE WHEN` like this:

public function findLatestPaginator($page = 1, $itemsPerPage)
{
    $qb = $this->createQueryBuilder('n');

```
$qb = $qb
    ->select(['n AS news', 'CASE WHEN lu.id IS NOT NULL THEN 1 ELSE 0 END AS n.liked'])
    ->leftJoin('n.likingUsers', 'lu')
;

$qb = $qb
    ->orderBy('n.date', 'DESC')
    ->setFirstResult($itemsPerPage * ($page - 1))
    ->setMaxResults($itemsPerPage)
    ->getQuery()
;

return $qb->getResult();
```

}

In my entity I have a field called `$liked` which is not mapped. Is it possible to make the query (or the hydrator?) automatically set the field on the resulting entity?

Right now I am making a `foreach` loop and manually setting the property:

```
/**
 * @return News[]
 */
private function convertNews(array $records)
{
    $newsList = [];

    foreach ($records as $record) {
        if (isset($record['liked'], $record['news'])) {
            /** @var News */
            $news        = $record['news'];
            $news->liked = boolval($record['liked']);
            $newsList[]  = $news;
        }
    }

    return $newsList;
}
```

Comment: Maybe [Custom Hydrator](https://www.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-orm/en/2.7/reference/dql-doctrine-query-language.html#custom-hydration-modes)  could do that. Also maybe extending DQL could do that.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe a DTO could be useful here : [doctrine documentation](https://www.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-orm/en/2.7/reference/dql-doctrine-query-language.html#new-operator-syntax)

Basically, you define a PHP class which is not mapped to your model.
You can then select what you need and trigger the instantiation of an object of this PHP class from the DQL query.

Hope this helps !

Answer (score -1):

Default hydrator does not include unmapped properties (wow, right?).
You want to override/extend doctrine/orm/lib/Docrtrine/ORM/Internal/Hydration/AbstractHydrator
line 386 where it only checks for $classMetadata fieldMappings

Or you can hack around by using DTO and query in transformer, if performance is not needed